# jquery ajax request multiple return values?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, get, request

I followed the tutorial from this page:

http://www.keyboardninja.eu/webdevelopment/jquery-ajax-call-tutorial

and already got the random number output. But how can I change the function (and the php file?), that I get multiple returns ("msg" in the example), to fill different divs? Or is that not possible, so I gotta fill the containing div with the stuff and put a whole lot of code into the echo part in the php file?

Thanks

Comment: put your js code here , so let me check

Comment: it is exactly the same as in the link:

function myCall() {
     var request = $.ajax({
      url: "ajax.php",
      type: "GET",   
      dataType: "html"
     });

     request.done(function(msg) {
      $("#mybox").html(msg);   
     });

     request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
      alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
     });
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in process.php file, add all messages in array than convert into json , as given below.

```
$msg=array();
$msg[]  = $msg1;
$msg[]  = $msg2;
.
.
........

echo json_encode($msg);
```

now process json in your ajax call to show all of your message using **each** in javascript

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

In your ajax file, append the multiple messages with '|' or '~' and when it gets return , split it in JS; and place it in your DIVs through innerHTML.

ex (in ajax)

```
echo $msg1.'|'.$msg2.'|'.$msg3;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Simple do this on Php side (ajax.php):

```
    $arr = array();
    $arr['msg1'] = '<p>Hi I am some random ' . rand() .' output from the server First Msg.</p>';
    $arr['msg2'] = '<p>Hi I am some random ' . rand() .' output from the server Second Msg.</p>';
    $arr['msg3'] = '<p>Hi I am some random ' . rand() .' output from the server Third Msg.</p>';
    echo json_encode($arr);
```

> And on Js side:

```
function myCall() {
  var request = $.ajax({
  url: "ajax.php",
  type: "GET",          
  dataType: "json"
  });

  request.done(function(data) {

    $("#mybox1").html(data.msg1);           
    $("#mybox2").html(data.msg2);           
    $("#mybox3").html(data.msg3);           
  });

  request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
     alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
  });
}
```